# Problema al ejecutar funciones con window.onload

Tags: javascript, eventos

`func2` funciona y desaparece después de 2 segundos, pero el primero `func1` no funciona, no se muestra el botón que tengo escondido. Me funcionaba antes de que añadiera el otro javascript `func2`, pero ya no.

Éste es mi código:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(func1, 2000);
};

function func1() {
  document.getElementById("hiddenbutton").className = "show";
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(func2, 2000);
};

function func2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").className = "hide";
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hiddenbutton" class="hide">
  <p>If the URL is correct, you can avoid waiting and touch the following button.</p>
  <form action="'.$longlink.'" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="button-'.$shortenedlink.'" disabled="disabled" value="Redirect">
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div id="div2" class="show">
  <p>The button will appear after 2 seconds of loading the page.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: El código no está completo, al menos falta la parte html. Véase [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén `<div id="hiddenbutton" class="hide"><p>If the URL is correct, you can avoid waiting and touch the following button.</p><form action="'.$longlink.'" method="post"><input type="submit" id="button-'.$shortenedlink.'" disabled="disabled" value="Redirect"></form></div><br><div id="div2" class="show"><p>The button will appear after 10 seconds of loading the page.</p></div>`

Answer (score 3):

La [respuesta de Jorhel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56497/250) es correcta: el problema que tienes es que estás asignando funciones al `onload` y entonces sólo se ejecutará la última porque sobreescribe las anteriores. Como alternativa a los métodos que pone en su solución, te diría que otra opción es que uses `addEventListener`. Algo como esto>

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { 
    // el código que quieres ejecutar
});
```

Al usar `addEventListener` para el método `load` en lugar de asignar funciones al `onload`, el código va a funcionar como quieres porque lo que hace es que pone las funciones en la cola de eventos (se ejecutarán en el orden en el que se asignan) en lugar de sobreescribirlas.

Cambiando tu código sólo un poco para sustituir el `onload` por el `addEventListener` quedaría así:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(func1, 2000);
});

function func1() {
  document.getElementById("hiddenbutton").className = "show";
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(func2, 2000);
});

function func2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").className = "hide";
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hiddenbutton" class="hide">
  <p>If the URL is correct, you can avoid waiting and touch the following button.</p>
  <form action="'.$longlink.'" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="button-'.$shortenedlink.'" disabled="disabled" value="Redirect">
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div id="div2" class="show">
  <p>The button will appear after 2 seconds of loading the page.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

aqui estás dandole un valor a onload con  =

```
window.onload=function()
{
    setTimeout(func1, 10000);
}
```

Y luego más adelante sobre escribes  window.onload y le asignas otro valor

```
window.onload=function()
{
    setTimeout(func2, 10000);    
};
```

como esta ultima es precisamente lo ultimo que le asignas a onload, por eso es que funciona y la otra no, porque se nulifica.

No hay problema si haces lo siguiente:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    setTimeout(func1, 10000);
    setTimeout(func2, 10000);  
    // aqui puedes añadir más funciones  
};
```

o si ambos setTimeout tendrán el mismo valor, hacer lo siguiente:

```
    window.onload=function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            func1();
            func2();
        }, 10000);
        // aqui puedes añadir más funciones  
    };
```